Как считывать клавиши с помощью bash на linux mint
Я хочу написать скрипт который при нажатии двух клавишь вызывает функицию. Как мне это сделать?
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
sed -n 's/[ ]state. ([^ ]))./\1/p'
done

а ваша клавиатура умеет отправлять что-то осмысленное при нажатии этих ваших двух (не озвученных) клавиш?
